# Angular @Inject problem when not value passes

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to use angular component for two purpous - as a full view and in dialog. In constructor 
`@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: number`, to pass variable. When I use it in dialog everything is OK. But when I use it as a full view then I can see blank page. I tried set default value to data, and set it as a nullable variable but it doesn't help. Perhapse you have some idea?

Answer (score 1):

@Optional before @Inject fix my problem.